# Regex to find results but ignore the commented # line

Tags: php, regex, file, comments, newline

I'm trying to use regex in PHP to find something in .ipmconf file.
 And the data inside the file is categorized in each [V //something] section.
This is my .ipmconf file looks like:

```
    [V5 sentry tuning]
    LossThreshold = some data here
    TopHostApplication = some data here
    #rt_comp_level : compression type allowed for "Real Time" flows
    rt_comp_level = some data here
    #tr_comp_level : compression type allowed for "Transactionnal" flows
    tr_comp_level = some data here
    #bg_comp_level : compression type allowed for "background" flows
    bg_comp_level = some data here
    tunnelcomport = some data here
    
    [V6 something]
    //other data here
```

Currently my code just able to read the data until the **"TopHostApplication = some data here"** line, and it stops there. So many data below that are missing, starting from the first comment.
How to ignore the #comments line and continue search another line until it arrive at last line?

here is some part my code:

```
                $filename = $_FILES['form']['name']['config'];
                $conf = file("./components/com_rsform/uploads/config".$filename);
                $buf = implode("\n",$conf);
                preg_match('/domain = (.*)/m',$buf,$match);
                $domain = $match[1];
                unlink("./com_rsform/uploads/config".$filename);
        
                while(!empty($conf)){
                   set_time_limit(240);
                   $line = array_shift ($conf);
                   if(preg_match('/^\[V\d+ (.*)\]/',$line,$match)){$section = $match[1];}
                      
                   if ($section == "sentry tuning"){
                      $data1 ="";$data2 ="";
                      while (preg_match('/^(.*) = (.*)$/',$line,$matches)){
                      $data1 = $matches[1]; 
                      $data2 = $matches[2]; 
                      $line = array_shift($conf);}
                      $section = "";
                   }
                   elseif($section == "[V6 something]")//next section
                   {//codes
                   }
                }
                //echo $data1 and $data2 somewhere here
```

I'm new with regex and PHP stuff. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why you put preg_match in a while loop? put it before the loop and loop through `$matches`

Comment: I tested your text and your rexeg on https://regex101.com/ and your regex is working fine

Comment: @Baracuda078 do i need to use preg_match_all? sorry I really new to this. (Please see my updated question and detail in it). Weirdly my program only show results until the TopHostApplication..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your regex to capture the complete section name. The following should process the entire configuration. I have added some `echo` statements:

```
while (!empty($conf)) {
    $line = array_shift($conf);
    if (!preg_match('/^\[(V\d+ .*)\]/',$line,$match)) { // slightly modified regex to get the complete section name
        continue;
    }
    $section = $match[1];
    echo "section = $section\n";
    if ($section == "V5 sentry tuning") {
        while (!empty($conf)) { // processes lines up until the next section
            $line = array_shift($conf);
            if (preg_match('/^\[(V\d+ .*)\]/',$line,$match)) { // start of a new section
                array_unshift($conf, $line); // put the line back to be processed by the next section
                break;
            }
            if (substr($line, 0, 1) == '#') { // a comment
                continue;
            }
            if (preg_match('/^(.*) = (.*)$/', $line, $matches)) {
                $data1 = $matches[1];
                $data2 = $matches[2];
                echo "data1 = $data1, data2 = $data2\n";
            }
        }
    }
    elseif ($section == 'V6 something') {
        // do something here
    }
}
echo "End of processing\n";
```

Prints:

```
section = V5 sentry tuning
data1 = LossThreshold, data2 = some data here
data1 = TopHostApplication, data2 = some data here
data1 = rt_comp_level, data2 = some data here
data1 = tr_comp_level, data2 = some data here
data1 = bg_comp_level, data2 = some data here
data1 = tunnelcomport, data2 = some data here
section = V6 something
End of processing
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop the the entire data, and extract the rows you want?

```
foreach ($conf as $line) {
    if(preg_match('/^(.*) = (.*)$/',$line,$matches)){
        $data1 = $matches[1]; 
        $data2 = $matches[2]; 

        //You presumably wanted to do something with $data1 and $data2 after this, but that's not in your example code :-)
    }
}
```

Incidentally: placing your entire loop on a single line, in the way you did, makes your code harder to read and has no effect on the size/efficiency of the compiled script whatsoever!

Comment: Thank you, thats great to know. But i cant just read the entire $conf because it will get results from all of the sections (eg. [V5 sentry tuning] , [V6 something else], etc.). Please see my updated question, I have edited it to add more detail for better understanding.